# DraftJs - Editor is adding entities to the wrong block when entities are added from EditorState.createWithContent()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, draftjs

**My goal**: Have my Editor pre-populated with some default text and immutable entities. The text portions that would be made entities would be strings that match to a list (`{{ immutable1 }}`, `{{ immutable2 }}`, etc...). If a person types in a string in the editor that matches the list of pre-defined tokens then that string that they just typed immediately gets decorated and set as an immutable entity.

**Problem**: When the default text that gets pre-populated into the editor contains tokens *in more than one block* then it breaks and seems to add tokens from the last block into the first block.

I'm populating the Editor with an initial state this way:

```
const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(DEFAULT_TEXT)
  const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
    blocksFromHTML.entityMap
  )
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
    EditorState.createWithContent(
      state,
      compositeDecorator
    )
  )

...

<Editor
 editorState={editorState}
 onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

This DEFAULT_TEXT works fine:

```
DEFAULT_TEXT = 'This is the first block {{ immutable1 }} with some tokens {{ immutable2 }}
This is 2nd block with no tokens. This works fine.
The tokens are immutable and if you type more then they will become immutable too'
```

This DEFAULT_TEXT breaks it:

```
DEFAULT_TEXT = 'This is the first block {{ immutable1 }} with some tokens {{ immutable2 }}
This 2nd block has a token {{ immutable3 }}. Apparently having a token in more than one block causes this issue.
Click anywhere in the editor and it will act erratically and add tokens.'
```

**How to reproduce**: Got to my codesandbox link below and click anywhere in the editor. You'll see it adds tokens `{{ immutable1 }}` and `{{ immutable3 }}` to the first block, for some reason. If you want to see it working without issues just comment out line 33.

Code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-lewin-quwcr?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the following line...

```
const currentSelectionState = nextState.getSelection()
```

with this...

```
const currentSelectionState = SelectionState.createEmpty(contentBlock.getKey())
```

That way you are always guaranteed to create the selection within the current block. Also, you may want to move your `setEditorState(nextState)` out of the two loops. There's no need to update it every time.